# Autocomplete for textbox using jQuery with a location in Session

Tags: c#, textbox, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have C# code that looks like [this](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Populate-jQuery-AutoComplete-TextBox-from-Database-using-Web-Service-in-ASPNet.aspx).

How do I add my `Session['location']` variable into the Sqlcommandtext so that the whole code will work.

I want my code to

```
cmd.CommandText = "select ContactName, CustomerId from Customers where " & 
"ContactName like @SearchText + '%' and Location1=@Location1";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefix)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location1", Session["location"]);
```

I got the exact same code as the link above but I need to add Session variable. 
This is where the error comes after I add in the Session.

Comment: What is the text of the error?

Comment: You need to show us error message and also I am suggesting you to check value of session before assigning it.

Comment: Try adding the session value to a variable (after having a null check) and it should work

Comment: My error message :Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException

Comment: So how do I edit my jquery code so that if it is null, it returns blank?

Comment: Removed tags from title; trademark capitalization; grammar; noise reduction.